# Simulatability of Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, key-exchange

While reading through [Shoup](https://shoup.net/papers/skey.pdf)'s paper on provably secure Diffie-Hellman key exchange (DHKE), I do not understand something rather simple.

There are two parties $A$ and $B$. $A$ starts by sending $g^a$, and then $B$ sends $g^b$. Both compute $g^{ab}$. For an adversary, $g^{ab}$ should be indistinguishable from a randomly chosen $g^c$. How would one simulate this without commitments?

This is like coin toss: in the ideal world, parties do not have an input, and the TTP just sends a random $g^c$ to each party. Honest parties output $g^c$ (and use it as a session key), and the adversary outputs anything they like.

Let me try to build a simulator. Specifically, in the ideal world, assume $B$ is the adversary. The simulator $S$ would receive $g^c$ from the TTP. What would $S$ forward to $A$? Without, e.g., commitment and ZK proof or random oracles how can $S$ know/extract $B$'s input $b$. $S$ has to send some $g^{a'}$ to $B$ such that $B$ can output $g^c=(g^{a'})^b$. That seems difficult.

If parties would first commit to their shares, things would be easy...